# PDF/A-3b with attachments: how to create an /AF entry at pdf catalog?

Tags: pdftex, pdf-a

I'm trying to produce a PDF/A-3b file with pdflatex. Everything is fine with fonts, colors, links... But I'm not able to create the `/AF` entry at Document Catalog.

I know I can start by `\pdfcatalog` command from pdflatex. But I don't know how to proceed.

I've created a github project with the minimal working example (mwe):

https://github.com/laurocesar/latex-pdfa3

Comment: There is no `/AF` entry in the PDF Catalog, at least according to ISO 32000-1.

Comment: @AlexG, the Adobe preflight summary report say this:

"Embedded file does not have AF entry";

"Embedded file has no AFRelationship entry";

"Embedded file present but no UF key";

Comment: The ISO is: ISO 19005-3:2012

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format. A suggestion: Do us a favour and change your username to something more telling than "user1234".

Comment: [CHF 158](http://www.iso.org/iso/catalogue_detail.htm?csnumber=57229) is too much. Sorry.

Comment: In 2014 I wrote a paper titled _PDF/A-3u as an archival format for Accessible mathematics_ which you can find here: `http://rutherglen.science.mq.edu.au/~maths/CICM/`.  The PDF structure of _Associated files_ is covered, with example coding being provided. — No Swiss francs needed.  :-)

Comment: @LauroCésar I've exactlly the same problem with AF entry and the AFRelationship.  Did you found a solution for that in the mean time?

Comment: @ozross-RRM I took a look at your paper. I found it under `https://arxiv.org/pdf/1406.6126.pdf`. I still don't understand how to set the `AF entry` and the `AFRelationship` using the `embedfile` package. I would be very nice if you could a an answer with an minimal code example.

Comment: This has been solved in the `embedfile` package, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/524647/139832