# PDF/A-3u with embedfile missing /AF entry and /AFRelationship entry

Tags: pdf-a, pdfx, embedfile

I'm having the following data file called `data.txt`:

```
Testdata
```

and the following LaTeX code called `test2.tex`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[a-3u]{pdfx}
\usepackage{embedfile}
\newcommand{\datafile}[2]{\embedfile[filespec={#2},ucfilespec={#2},filesystem=URL,mimetype=application/octet-stream,desc={#2},stringmethod=escape]{#1#2}}

\datafile{}{data.txt}

\begin{document}
Bla bla ...
\end{document}
```

Using `pdfLaTeX` I can generate a PDF which claims that it is PDF/A-3u.

If I verify this PDF with Adobe Preflight I get the following errors:

- Embedded file does not have /AF entry
- Embedded file has no /AFRelationship entry

[image]

If I use veraPDF V1.10.6 to verify the PDF I get the following errors:

[image]

How can I solve those problems?

I've seen that others have similar problems, see [PDF/A-3b with attachments: how to create an /AF entry at pdf catalog?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/223860/pdf-a-3b-with-attachments-how-to-create-an-af-entry-at-pdf-catalog)

**Update**

I found the following source describing the /AF entry and the /AFRelationship entry, see https://arxiv.org/pdf/1406.6126.pdf. I do not fully understand it.

If I take a look at the uncompressed pdf file, where the embed file is described, it looks like that:

```
5 0 obj
<</Type/Filespec/FS/URL/F(data.txt)/UF(data.txt)/Desc(data.txt)/EF<</F 4 0 R>>>>
endobj
```

If this would be changed to

```
5 0 obj
<</Type/Filespec/FS/URL/F(data.txt)/UF(data.txt)/Desc(data.txt)/AFRelationship/Unspecified/EF<</F 4 0 R>>>>
endobj
```

then there should be no missing /AFRelationship entry anymore.

And somewhere there should be `/AF[5 0 R 5 0 R]` to solve the missing /AF entry.

Comment: I don't think that pdfx can do something about it as it is embedfiles which writes the dictionaries etc. It is difficult to write code for this as their is no free source describing which entries should be in the different locations in the pdf.

Comment: The follwoing link describes how to generate a PDF/A-3 document using iText, see https://developers.itextpdf.com/tutorial/pdfa-3-itext. I'm not sure if the source of iText is open. If so this could be translated to LaTeX.

Comment: For the font error (6.2.11.4) of veraPDF, see as well https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/426946/pdf-a-1b-adobe-preflight-verification-passes-and-verapdf-fails.

Comment: I added a new issue at github, see https://github.com/ho-tex/oberdiek/issues/37.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `/AF` and `/AFrelationship` keys have been added to the `embedfile` package in version 2.9 from 2019/12/03.

See https://ctan.org/pkg/embedfile

The `/AFrelationship` has to be set with the following command:

```
\newcommand{\datafile}[2]{
  \embedfile[
    filespec={#2},
    ucfilespec={#2},
    filesystem=URL,
    mimetype=application/octet-stream,
    afrelationship={/Data},
    desc={#2},stringmethod=escape
  ]{#1#2}}
```

Then the generated PDF will pass the PDF/A-3U validation using veraPDF V1.14.8.

Comment: If you want to include something else than raw data you should use the corresponding `afrelationship`. `/Source` i.e. is for the tex source, `/Alternative` for an audio version of the PDF or `/Unspecified` for other. The slash is optional. The `embedfile` doc about this is completely wrong at the moment.

Comment: @tanGIS Please add a new issue at https://github.com/ho-tex/embedfile/issues