# PDF/A-1b: Adobe Preflight verification passes and veraPDF fails

Tags: pdf-a, pdfx

I'm having the following LaTeX code called `test1b`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[a-1b]{pdfx}

\begin{document}
Bla bla ...
\end{document}
```

Using `pdfLaTeX` I can generate a PDF which claims that it is PDF/A-1b.

If I verify this PDF with Adobe Preflight it passes.

If I use veraPDF V1.10.6 to verify the PDF it fails and I get the following error:

[image]

See Rule [6.3.4-1](https://github.com/veraPDF/veraPDF-validation-profiles/wiki/PDFA-Part-1-rules#rule-634-1). How can I solve this problem?

Comment: As pdflatex embeds this font the validation message is probably wrong, so complain to veraPDF. They have a github page: https://github.com/veraPDF

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I added a new issue at github, see https://github.com/veraPDF/veraPDF-library/issues/957.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has been a bug in veraPDF V1.10.6. This has been fixed in V1.11.19, see https://github.com/veraPDF/veraPDF-library/issues/957.

> I confirm this has been an issue in PostScript font parser in the
>   1.10.6 release. It has been fixed in dev. Please check the latest dev version:
>   http://software.verapdf.org/develop/1.11/verapdf-greenfield-1.11.19-installer.zip