# Embedding font Merriweather into a valid PDF/a-1B

Tags: fonts, pdf-a

I am currently trying to create a fully valid PDF/A-1B. The problem here seems to be that I am using the font "Merriweather Light". When I validate my PDF using VeraPDF, I get errors of two types:

```
Rule    Status
Specification: ISO 19005-1:2005, Clause: 6.3.5, Test number: 1  
Embedded font programs shall define all font glyphs referenced for rendering with conforming file.  Failed
2 occurrences   Hide
Glyph   
renderingMode == 3 || isGlyphPresent == null || isGlyphPresent == true  
root/document[0]/pages[240](4150 0 obj PDPage)/contentStream[0](4151 0 obj PDContentStream)/operators[128]/usedGlyphs[5](BAPWVJ+Merriweather-LightIt 69 0 0)
...
```

and

```
Specification: ISO 19005-1:2005, Clause: 6.3.6, Test number: 1  
For every font embedded in a conforming file and used for rendering, the glyph width information in the font dictionary and in the embedded font program shall be consistent.   Failed
117 occurrences Hide
Glyph   
renderingMode == 3 || isWidthConsistent == null || isWidthConsistent == true    
root/document[0]/pages[240](4150 0 obj PDPage)/contentStream[0](4151 0 obj PDContentStream)/operators[94]/usedGlyphs[30](VWCVXM+Merriweather-Light 79 0 0)
...
```

Other errors/problems do not seem to show up.

My preamble looks like this:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{style}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[a-1b]{pdfx}

\usepackage[light]{merriweather}
```

Anyone knows how to get Merriweather embedded in an PDF/A without errors?

As per request, here is a MWE that reproduces the problem:

```
\documentclass[10pt,chapterinoneline,english,onehalfspacing,headsepline]{style}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[a-1b]{pdfx}

%\usepackage{palatino} % <-- this works and gets verified (yet looks utterly ugly)
\usepackage[light]{merriweather}

\begin{document}

lorem ipsum

\end{document}
```

Comment: Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: As pdflatex embeds this font the first validation message is probably wrong, so complain to veraPDF. See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/426946/pdf-a-1b-adobe-preflight-verification-passes-and-verapdf-fails

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Thanks for this hint! Still, they claim to have this issue fixed by now in the GitHub issue you created. I'm using veraPDF 1.12.1 BTW.
I tried jPDFPreflight hence. Throws similar problems: "Type1 font subset: PJDPQP+SFTT0900 Charset Incomplete"

Comment: I don't have your class, but with book, adobe preflight says everything is ok.

Comment: VeraPDF reports no errors, if you compile your MWE with `lualatex`

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Interesting. What pdflatex version and OS are you using? With the book class, VeraPDF still wont verify the documents with the errors posted before. I am using MacOSX 10.13.5 with TexLive 2017 (pdfTex 3.14)

Comment: I'm on windows 10 and I think I checked with texlive 2018 but it could also be miktex. In any case: I used adobe preflight to validate. And I'm quite certain that pdflatex embeds the characters.

Comment: I updated to TexLive 2018 now. VeraPDF yields the same errors for the same MWE. At the same time, jPDFpreflight (which also reported errors with TexLive 2017) does NOT report any more errors. At the same time, my original document yields the same errors in both programs. Will attempt to recreate your results later on Win10 with MikTex.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer On Windows 10 now. I am using MikTex 2.9.6630 and TexStudio 2.12.8 and all updates. VeraPDF throws the same errors as with Mac OSX for the MWE above. Will have to check the Adobe Preflight option...

Comment: Digging a bit deeper: The pdfx-package throws this warning: "Some font shapes were not available, defaults substituted." and "Font shape T1/Merriweather-OsF/l/sc undefined(Font) using T1/Merriweather-OsF/l/n instead"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, it seems that I've found the error. Or at least got the document to get verified.

When compiling with lualatex instead of pdflatex, the compiler encoutered a problem with a unicode character in my bib-file. Specifically, a `ç` wasn't properly escaped via `\c{c}`. While this didn't cause any problems compiling with pdflatex and produced a readable document, lualatex protested loudly. After fixing this, luatatex compiles without problems and the resulting pdf is PDF/A-1B compliant according to veraPDF :)

Interestingly, the same (!) document compiled with pdflatex still fails verification with same same errors. Moreover, jPDFPreflight still fails to verify both the lualatex and pdflatex versions.

Also, this doesn't explain to me the failing verification of the MWE above as it has no bibfile included. Then again it apparently only fails to verify for me.

Anyhow, I hope this might help others to narrow down possible errors in their documents :)